# Linq to Objects - Summing groupby count

Tags: c#, linq, object, group-by, sql-order-by

I've got a Linq to Objects Question

We're manufacturing products and trying to report lossCodes by Month, sorted by aggregate lossCode.

So source data (as **List< myProduct > myProducts**) would look like:

```
.lossDate / .lossCode
4/10/2012 / TooLarge
4/11/2012 / TooSmall
4/14/2012 / TooSmall
4/14/2012 / TooSmall
4/14/2012 / TooSmall
5/1/2012  / TooLarge
5/10/2012 / TooSmall
4/10/2012 / TooLarge
5/10/2012 / WrongColor
```

The result transformation should look like:

```
        |  TooSmall |  TooLarge | WrongColor
04-2102 |    4      |    2      |    0
05-2012 |    1      |    1      |    1
```

So it's a group by (month, lossCode) ... plus a sort on 'aggregate' loss (so TooSmall cnt=5 then TooLarge cnt=3 then WrongColor cnt=1 is the sort order I'm trying to get) - but I'm having problems with the final sort.

```
query = from prod in myProducts
  group prod by new {Month = prod.lossDate.ToString("yyyy-MM"), prod.lossCode} into g
  select new
  {
     g.Key.Month,                   
     ReasonCode = g.Key.lossCode,
     NumLosses = g.Count()
  }
  into resultSet
  orderby resultSet.NumLosses descending
  select resultSet;
```

This code is undeniably wrong (orderby resultSet.NumLosses is clearly not correct) ... but I don't understand how to Sum the subgroup Counts to be able to do the final sort. Due to some other uses of the result set I'd rather not attempt to graft a 'totals' record onto the result set (and with the anonymous types I'm not precisely sure how it would be done). Anyone been through something like this before?

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to order by `NumLosses`

```
query = (from prod in myProducts
  group prod by new {Month = prod.lossDate.ToString("yyyy-MM"), prod.lossCode} into g
  select new
  {
     g.Key.Month,                   
     ReasonCode = g.Key.lossCode,
     NumLosses = g.Count()
  }
).OrderByDescending(x => c.NumLosses)
```

Comment: (oops - yes, numLosses)  

I'm not sure this gets me the right result - If I'm not mistaken, this .OrderByDescending clause will sort on numLosses for the [Month, lossCode] grouping ... what I'm trying to do is sort on aggregate numLosses for a given lossCode regardless of date. Ugh - does that explanation make any sense?